# chained ternary operator in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to format it easily so anyone can understand the end output. Otherwise i want to recode using if condition. Could anyone help me understand the following code and format it in more presentable understanding way.

```
validate: function() {
    return this.getRequired() && 
   !this.getValue() ? 
        (this.showError("Required"), !1) 
        : this.getValue() ? 
        "email" != this.getType() || this.isValidEmail() ? 
            "email_username" != this.getType() || this.isValidEmail() || this.isValidUsername() ? 
                    "username" != this.getType() || this.isValidUsername() ?
                            "roomid" != this.getType() || this.isValidUsername() ? 
                                        "displayName" != this.getType() || this.isValidDisplayName() ? 
                                                    "phone" != this.getType() || this.isValidPhone() ? !0 
                                                    : (this.showError("Enter a valid phone number"), !1) 
                                        :(this.showError("Enter both first and last names"), !1)  
                            :(this.showError("Enter a valid meeting room ID"), !1) 
                    :(this.showError("Enter a valid username"), !1) 
            :(this.showError("Enter a valid email address or username"), !1) 
        :(this.showError("Enter a valid email address"), !1) 
    : !0
}
```

Comment: using a switch on `this.getType()` seems a better solution here. (Thanks, @Barmar for correcting the brain-fart).

Comment: There's no way to format this so that it will be understandable. Nested ternaries are inherently confusing, just don't do it.

Comment: Yeah, that code is an unreadable mess. You could look for an online javascript formatter.

Comment: I've occasionally done one level of nesting when it's very short, I would never do what you're trying.

Comment: Those `!1` instances are totally surreal. It's like this code was designed to be as obnoxiously obtuse as possible.

Answer (score 1):

not sure if this would work?

```
var items = ['email', 'email_username', 'etc'];
for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++){
    switch(items[i]){
        case 'email':
            if(items[i] != this.getType || items[i].isValidEmail())
            this.showError('Enter a valid email address'), !1) 
            break;
        case 'email_username':
            if(items[i] != this.getType || items[i].isValidEmail() || this.isValidUsername())
            this.showError('Enter a valid email address'), !1) 
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: not going to be as efficient, but its certainly easier to follow

Comment: When doing form validation, efficiency is hardly ever a concern. How many clicks per second can a user perform? A half dozen?

Answer (score 0):

Here's part of the code, I only did for email. You will need to do for the rest:

```
validate: function () {
    var type = this.getType();
    var isValid = true;
    if (this.getRequired() && !this.getValue()) {
        switch (type) {
            case "email":
                if (!this.isValidEmail()) {
                    isValid = false;
                    this.showError("Enter a valid email address")
                }
                break;
            case "email_username":
                break;
            case "username":
                break;
            case "roomid":
                break;
            case "displayName":
                break;
            case "phone":
                break;
        }
    }
    return isValid;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This actually isn't unreadable. It's the formatting that's bad. I would format it like so:

```
return this.getRequired() && !this.getValue()
    ? (this.showError("Required"), false) 
    : this.getValue() 
        ? "email" != this.getType() || this.isValidEmail() 
            ? "email_username" != this.getType() || this.isValidEmail() || this.isValidUsername() 
                ? "username" != this.getType() || this.isValidUsername() 
                    ? "roomid" != this.getType() || this.isValidUsername() 
                        ? "displayName" != this.getType() || this.isValidDisplayName()
                            ? "phone" != this.getType() || this.isValidPhone() 
                                ? true 
                                : (this.showError($L("Enter a valid phone number")), false) 
                            : (this.showError("Enter both first and last names"), false)  
                        : (this.showError("Enter a valid meeting room ID"), false) 
                    : (this.showError("Enter a valid username"), false) 
                : (this.showError("Enter a valid email address or username"), false) 
            : (this.showError("Enter a valid email address"), false) 
        : true
```

It definitely seems rough, but it saves on a ton of separate return statements, along the lines of "if this, then return this, else if this, return this...." etc.

Also, yeah, the `!1` syntax is completely superfluous.

Edit: The reason that a switch doesn't work here is because the logic is nested. You'd either end up with nested if statements that replace the ternaries, or you would have to rewrite the logic. If it's working....great. Get it under test and see if it's possible to refactor. If not....I hope you have the business rules for this thing.

Answer (score 0):

why not use some more readable format like this:

```
validate: function () {
    var ok = false;
    switch (true) {
        case (this.getRequired() && !this.getValue()):
            this.showError("Required");
            break;
        case ("email" === this.getType() && !this.isValidEmail()):
            this.showError("Enter a valid email address");
            break;//                                         
        case ("email_username" === this.getType() && (!this.isValidEmail() || !this.isValidUsername())):
            this.showError("Enter a valid email address or username");
            break;
        case ("username" === this.getType() && !this.isValidUsername()):
            this.showError("Enter a valid username");
            break;
        case ("roomid" === this.getType() && !this.isValidUsername()):
            this.showError("Enter a valid meeting room ID");
            break;
        case ("displayName" === this.getType() && !this.isValidDisplayName()):
            this.showError("Enter both first and last names");
            break;
        case ("phone" !== this.getType() && !this.isValidPhone()):
            this.showError($L("Enter a valid phone number"));
            break;
        default: ok = true;
    }
    return ok;
}
```